# Passing param using command link but it working only on double click

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

```
<apex:commandlink Value="Add Batch" action="{!addBatch}" reRender="pb,errormsg" >
<apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" value="{!rowNum}" name="qliRowNum" />
<apex:param assignto="{!Batchesnumber}" value="{!qli.No_Of_Batches__c}" name="Batchesnumber"/>
</apex:commandlink>
```

The above code is working  only on double click

If i directly kept for

value="{!qli.No_Of_Batches__c}"

to

Manually keep the value for this

value="3"

then it is working fine on single click .what could be the issue

I want to pass user value it is taking the value but working only if double click

How to make work with single click ?

code :

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!batchMap[qliRow]}" var="child" id="therepeat2">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="inTble{!batchrowNum}">
<tr>
<td ></td>                 
<td><b>Asked Quantity</b></td>
<td>No of batches</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:135px;"><apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(batchrowNum)}"/></td>                   
<td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.batchObj.Asked_Qty__c}" required="true" style="width:110px"/></td>
<td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.batchObj.No_Of_Batches__c}" required="true" style="width:110px"/></td>
 <td>
  <apex:commandlink Value="Add Batch" action="{!addBatch}" reRender="pb" styleclass="btn">
 <apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" value="{!qliRow}" name="qliRowNum" /><apex:param assignto="{!Batchesnumber}" value="{!child.batchObj.No_Of_Batches__c}" name="Batchesnumber"/>
</apex:commandlink>
</td>   

 </tr>
 <apex:variable var="batchrowNum" value="{!batchrowNum+ 1}"/>  
 </table>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: This part seems ok. Maybe there is some issue in some other part of the code. Are you iterating through a list? You could post that as well..

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute and `name` attribute of `<apex:param>` should refer to the same if `value` attribute reference a bind variable. This is not documented anywhere to my knowledge.

So change this

```
<apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" value="{!rowNum}" name="qliRowNum" />
<apex:param assignto="{!Batchesnumber}" value="{!qli.No_Of_Batches__c}" name="Batchesnumber"/>
```

to

```
<apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" value="{!rowNum}" name="{!rowNum}" />
<apex:param assignto="{!Batchesnumber}" value="{!qli.No_Of_Batches__c}" name="{!qli.No_Of_Batches__c}"/>
```

Hope this helps.